# Django-admin-bootstapped and summernote in admin.py

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, django-admin, summernote

I've just installed django-summernote and wish to add it on one of my admin page.
I've followed the installation guide but their is no summernote display.
I didn't found anything related to this.

Here is my code :
In admin.py (**event_app**):

```
class StaticEventAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (_('Event informations'), {
            'fields': (
                'name',
                'start',
                'end',
                'description',
            )
        })
    )
admin.site.register(StaticEvent, StaticEventAdmin)
```

In models.py (**event_app**):

```
class StaticEvent(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=255)
        start = models.DateTimeField(_("Start"))
        end = models.DateTimeField(_("End"))
        description = models.CharField(_("Description"), max_length=255)

        def __str__(self):
            return _("{0}").format(
                self.name,
            )
```

In urls.py (**main_app**):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        ...
        (r'^summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
        ...
    )
```

The folder structure is like this :

```
main_app
    urls.py
    models.py
    settings.py

    event_app
        urls.py
        models.py
        admin.py
```

I'm using django-admin-bootstrapped.
And here the sample of settings.py to have SummernoteInplaceWidget :

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    # Using SummernoteWidget - iframe mode
    'iframe': False,
}
```

So i'm wondering if there is conflict between django-bootstrapped-admin and summernote?

I have a doubt arround the main_app/urls.py, is there something else to do when we are working onto a sub-app?

I wish to have description field with summernote. Can you help me please?
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. The summernote guide explicitly say that thing :

```
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin

# Apply summernote to all TextField in model.
class SomeModelAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
```

And i thought any field with text are TextField (so i thought CharField was a TextField...)

Thank you all.